# Binding searching in the wrong place

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, converters

I'm trying to bind a on an IsEnabled property to check if the GridColumn can be edited or not. 
Now the Binding I did like this

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Quantity Shipped" UniqueName="QuantityShipped" DataMemberBinding="{Binding QuantityShipped}" IsEnabled="{Binding TblLstStatus.StatusValue, Converter={StaticResource StatusValToBool},ConverterParameter='20;200'}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyleNormal}">
```

Now I get this Binding error

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TblLstStatus' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModelSalesOrder' (HashCode=1285414)'. BindingExpression:Path=TblLstStatus.StatusValue; DataItem='ViewModelSalesOrder' (HashCode=1285414); target element is 'GridViewDataColumn' (HashCode=55181770); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')
```

For some reason the compiler is searching the wrong place for the object TblLstStatus and I have no clue why..

Grid Declaration

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="dataGridDetail" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" ItemsSource={Binding SelectedItem.TblDatODSales, ElementName=dataGrid}" Background="{x:Null}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
RowHeight="20" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" IsFilteringAllowed="false" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged"
EditTriggers="Default,CellClick">
```

Parent Grid

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Background="{x:Null}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
RowHeight="20" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowGroupPanel="True" IsFilteringAllowed="true" SelectionMode="Single" 
MouseDoubleClick="dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" EditTriggers="Default,CellClick">
```

Data operation (DevForce)

```
query = query.Include("TblLstStatus")
                         .Include("TblLstStaff_Req")
                         .Include("TblLstStaff_Resp")
                         .Include("TblLstOrganisation_Req")
                         .Include("TblDatODSales.TblLstART")
                         .Include("TblDatODSales.TblLstStatus").OrderByDescending(c => c.CreationDate);

            statusQuery = statusQuery.Include("TblLstStatusType");

            _dataService.GetManager().ExecuteQueryAsync(query, argsv =>
            {
                if (argsv.Error == null && argsv.Results != null)
                {
                    this.Orders = new ObservableCollection<TblDatOrderSales>(argsv.Results);
                }
            }, null);
```

Things I've tried

- Adding entire object path to the binding
- Changed to ReadOnly (same error)

Comment: *For some reason the compiler is searching the wrong place for the object TblLstStatus*... incorrect... *you* are searching in the wrong place. I can only assume that you have `ViewModelSalesOrder` items in your collection, so where else should a `DataGridColumn` look for its data except in a row object? You need to show your data hierarchy before anyone can work out what the *actual* `Binding Path` should be.

Comment: If you bind a collection to a DataGrid shouldn't the given collection be the content of the ItemSource ?